# Unity car speedometer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made digital speedometer for my car, it shows speed normally, but when car is standing at 0km/h speedometer digits jumping very fast up and down, so I wanted to ask how to fix it and I need to make it show integer, because now there are many digits after coma. Here is code that I use:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class greitis : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject GreitisDisplay,masina;
    public Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
    Vector3 abc;
    float greituks;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        m_Rigidbody = masina.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        abc = m_Rigidbody.velocity;
        greituks = abc.magnitude;
        GreitisDisplay.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "" + greituks*3.6;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get an integer you could use:

```
Mathf.Round(greituks*3.6)
```

Comment: ok, but how to fix that it was not showing jumping speed when car is Standing?

Comment: If it's the decimals that are "jumping" up and down, the round should fix that too.

Comment: Thnx, but when I try to round I get 2 errors 1: Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Mathf.Round(float)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (Assembly-CSharp) and 2 error: Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float' (CS1503) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: add an f just after 3.6 (to make it a float).

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as solved or useful. :^)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`GreitisDisplay.GetComponent ().text = "" + (int)(greituks*3.6);`

Since `m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude` will always give you `float`. So, it's safe to do it like this.